# "Play/Pause" button on remote does nothing, Apple TV 4K

Tags: appletv, remote-control, 4k

The "Play/Pause" button in the lower left corner of the remote control for the Apple TV 4K has no effect. Previously it stopped and started videos playing in apps such as Netflix.

Workaround: Clicking the physical button under the touch surface stops and starts the playing of videos.

Is there a feature, some setting, that may be altering this button’s behavior?

I am on the Apple’s beta channel for this Apple TV. Could this be some new feature in [tvOS 11.3 beta recently installed](https://9to5mac.com/2018/01/24/tvos-11-3-beta-1/)?

Comment: I am also on tvOS 11.3 beta. I updated it last night and have noticed the same issue. When I press the button the LED light on the Apple TV receiver blinks however it does not play or pause the content that is playing.

Comment: Same here, Play / Pause button does nothing on tvOS 11.3 public beta 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankfully they have just fixed this issue.  If you update to the latest Beta version, it works again.

Comment: Indeed, the Play/Pause button does again function in the latest beta release of tvOS 11.3.